# What's the name of MS's (ongoing?) embedded (serverless) SQL Server version with stored procedures support?

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-express, embedded-database

Some months ago I've read an announce of Microsoft to be going to release an embedded (serverless, linked to an application as a library/assembly and using a simple file to store data) SQL Server version to replace (for those needing this, not to replace at all) SQL Server Express (full-functional but needing a separate server software to be installed) and SQL Server Compact (embedded but low-functional - without stored procedures, triggers etc.) and support all the candies like stored procedures and triggers.

But I've forgotten how was it meant to be named and can't find it now.

Do you know of this?

Comment: Wow. That's a real monster sentence ;-)

Comment: @daniel-hilgarth, I'm a drunken Russian, that's it :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's called LocalDB:

[Introducing LocalDB, an improved SQL Express](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx)

Note that SQL CE does not support "Procedural T-SQL" (Select Case, If, etc) or Stored procedures, views, and triggers. In other words it is "light and tight" but that comes at a price.

MS has *not* released an embedded SQL database that supports stored procedures.

You might have a look at [VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net/) if those are your requirements.

Comment: AFAIK "SQL Server Compact" is a synonym to "SQL Server Anywhere", no SPs.

Comment: @Ivan: There is no such thing called "SQL Server Anywhere". Its name is "SQL Server Compact Edition".

Comment: @daniel-hilgarth, as far as I can remember it used to be called so, at its early days least. But thanks, I'll correct the question.

Comment: SQL server express is not based on MSDE it is a fully featured SQL server with some function disabled and some limits on CPU/memory

Comment: @kevin-ross, who said MSDE? I've only thought of it, not wrote. You're a telepath!

Comment: @Kevin: It's possible I read more into [this](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/4/7/A47B7B0E-976D-4F49-B15D-F02ADE638EBE/Compact_Express_Comparison.doc) than was intended, but it seems deliberate: "SQL Server Express Edition is the evolution of MSDE".

Comment: @hemp You did read too much into it, SQL Express is the natural successor of MSDE in that it is a free server based database however it is not based on MSDE at all and does not have any of the MSDE style “user throttling” or anything like that. They did this (IMHO) to get a smoother upgrade path so once you outgrow the express edition you can just do an in place upgrade as the DB engine is the same apart from the disabled features and limitations

Comment: @Kevin: Yeah I'm fully aware of what SQL Express offers - I've used it many times for multiple projects. It's outstanding when you want a SQL Server "light" experience at zero cost. But that does not automatically mean none of the MSDE core was used to build it. I have no data to back up either position, so I'm just as content to see it your way.